# Alarm App for iOS with Flutter in Visual Studio Code

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code, notifications, alarmmanager

I started programming half a year ago. Before that I had nothing to do with it. The reason for this is a project work, in which I have undertaken to write an alarm clock app. I have familiarized myself with the program Flutter, but now just do not get on. My goal is the following:

A simple app, written with Flutter in Visual Studio Code, with a "+" button, with which you can add a new alarm time. At this time the alarm should ring and I get a notification. You can think of it in terms of setup, like Apple's alarm clock app, but much more straightforward. My app also has a second view where the time is shown. However, I have managed to do this. In the attachment I send pictures of my current App. [View of my app first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziCI2.png)

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this. I have been trying for so long and have looked at just about every tutorial. I am on the verge of despair as I need to be done with it soon as well.

Comment: Where do you need help exactly? Please provide the code you already wrote to see how much you achieved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TripleNine I don't have anything for the alarm clock page yet. All my attempts have failed. I would be very grateful for your help. I could send you my File so you can see  my homepage and the bottom navigation bar. But, I do not know how to share a whole project here.